# Porting C++ code from Windows to Linux - Header files case sensitivity issue

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am porting a C++ large project form Windows to Linux. My C++ files include header files that do not match those on the project directory due to the case sensitivity of file names in Linux file systems.

Any help?

I would prefer finding a flag for gcc (or ext4 file system) to manual editing or sed'ing my files.

Thanks for all!

Comment: You really need to fix your code base rather than looking for kludges to temporarily help you avoid fixing it.

Comment: Duplicate (earlier today): [make file running on Linux - how to ignore case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138743/make-file-running-on-linux-how-to-ignore-case-sensitive)

Comment: Thank you, it seems better to start this work now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're out of luck on your preference. Linux is case-sensitive, and always will be. Just identify the names that need to be changed, and sed away.

Comment: Needless to mention that C++ itself is case sensitive and in the standard the header file are all specified in lower case. Though I see nothing definitive in the C99 about the case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the problem is with the file system. Unix file systems are case sensitive while windows ones are not. As far as I know there is no way round this. gcc certainly has no flags to help with this.

One point to bear in mind is directory separators. You can always safely use forward slashes "/" in #includes. This will work even for Windows.